# Image Filters/ByteArray

Tags: flash, apache-flex, pixel-bender

I am using pixel bender's pbj files(as recommended with Flex4) to change the brightness/contrast of a image.So i apply the filters to the image like this:

image.filters = myBitmapFilter;

Now my problem is **how to fetch the byteArray of the image with filter applied** so that i can send bytearray to my servlet which can save the image with applied effects.
Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options.  First, get the bitMapData.  You should be able to get this:

```
var myBitMapData : BitMapData = image.bitMapData
```

If not that, can you use the [imageDisplay skin Part](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html#SkinPartSummary), which is a [BitMapImage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/BitmapImage.html)?

```
var myBitMapData : BitMapData = image.imageDisplay.bitMapData
```

[Caveat; I'm not sure if the filters will be applied in either situation].

Once you have that BitMapData, you can get a ByteArray using the [getPixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixels%28%29) method:

```
var myByteArray : ByteArray = myBitMapData.getPixels(new Rectangle(0,0,image.width,image.height ));
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help..The above mentioned code to fetch the byte array worked absolutely fine.To get the bitmapdata and retaining all the filters i am using bitmapData.draw(image)

Comment: Glad to hear this helped.  If you think this fully answers your question, please select it as such.